# Can AWS redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

### Background

I am serving an application on AWS using Route53 + LoadBalancer + EC2.

I want to force all users to use https. Whenever a request is made on http, I want it redirected to a https request.

### Potential Solutions

I know of three ways to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

1. Client side. This involves using JS to check if the host is http or https, and redirecting if it's https.
2. Server Side. This involves configuring the webserver to redirect all http requests to https.
3. However, I'm curious: can this be done at the Route53 or LoadBalancer stage?

### Question

Is there some way to configure Route53 or LoadBalancer so that any requests on http are redirected to https?

Thanks!

### Edit

For downvoters: please explain why you are down voting. The solutions I have found on SO / Google are "how do do redirection via server, which is option 2. I'm trying to solve this at the AWS layer."

Comment: You have to do this on the EC2 instance. And you will need to check the `x-forwarded-proto` header to determine if the user has an HTTPS connection with the load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in doing 'client side redirect'. By the time the JS runs and does the redirect, is way too late. The request response content has already leaked all over the net. You **must** do it at the server side, respond with a [301 status and Location header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301), and no content. This can and should be done by your Web server stack (nginx, Apache) *before* hitting your app (php, node, etc).

ELB does not support redirect. It supports SSL/TLS *offloading* by *forwarding* the HTTPS traffic to HTTP target group and adding the `X-Forwarded-proto` headers, see [How do I redirect HTTP traffic on my server to HTTPS on my load balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/). But *redirect* must be handled by your back end server.

**Latest Update:**
AWS announces support for Redirects and Fixed Responses for Application Load Balancer with two new actions: redirect and fixed-response. This way you can configure the HTTP to HTTPS redirection at the Load Balancer Level.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve had the same problem and this is how I solved it:

cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk

nano 00_application.conf

add this inside

```
...

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://example.com [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

service httpd restart

Clear cookies from web browser and try the http to see if redirects

Answer (score 0):

The AWS method to solve this is via AWS Cloudfront. You buy a URL through Route53 (you don't have to), then you create an SSL certificate within AWS certificate manager then you set up AWS cloudfront (where you need the certificate you just set up). Hey presto, site delivered to SSL with all the security of AWS set up for you and a very fast delivery service.